# Trane humidifier control switch replacement

Tags: switch, heat-pump, humidifier

The control switch that came with bypass humidifier installed with my Trane heat pump started acting up - only turns humidifier water on when I turn the dial all the way to max. I'm thinking I need to replace it. It seems to have only 2 contacts, so my guess is I can just buy any other control switch, like this one and put it in instead:

https://smile.amazon.com/Aprilaire-4655-Manual-Humidistat/dp/B002VNEZX2/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1479092706&sr=8-3&keywords=humidifier+control+switch

Am I right, or there's more to it?

thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Replaced control switch, everything works great.